# Custom text in Excel using Macro for value between the two numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of data from 1-100 and I want to classify it in 4 zones:

```
Zone A : 0 < val <= 20
Zone B : 20 < val <= 40
Zone C : 40 < val <= 60
Zone D : 60 < val <= 100
```

How can I put the Zone A, B, C and D in front of it using some macro in .xls?

Comment: `select case` will be a good start for your research.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav did you forget the hyperlink?

Comment: No, google that in vba

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like so

```
Function zone_num(intNum As Integer)

zone_num = IIf(intNum < 0, "Error -ve", _
            IIf(intNum < 20, "Zone A", _
            IIf(intNum < 40, "Zone B", _
            IIf(intNum < 60, "Zone C", _
            IIf(intNum < 100, "Zone D", _
            "Error too high")))))

End Function
```

This is also possible in worksheet formula like so

`=CHOOSE(MATCH(H14,{0,21,41,61}),"a","b","c","d")` or using `index` and `match` as @JvdV says.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to Rome in this case, for example `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

---

***<sub>Sample data:</sub>***

[image]

---

***<sub>Code:</sub>***

```
Sub Test()

'Specify variables and populate arrays
Dim zNom As Variant: zNom = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
Dim zVal As Variant: zVal = Array(0, 21, 41, 61)
Dim lr As Long, x As Long, arr As Variant

With Sheet1'Change according to your sheets CodeName

    'Find last used row in column and fill array
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:A" & lr)

    'Go through array and repopulate it
    With Application
        For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            arr(x, 1) = .Index(zNom, .Match(arr(x, 1), zVal)) & arr(x, 1)
        Next x
    End With

    'Write new array to range
    .Range("A1:A" & lr) = arr

End With

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Result:</sub>***

[image]

Comment: This returns >100 as zone d, think op, wants a 100 cutoff too

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, OP states that his data sits from 1-100. Therefor I think it would be fine. Just wanted to post my take on this. An UDF, as yours, sounds very fitting, hence why I upvoted.

Comment: It wasn't a criticism, was testing yours in relation to mine :)

Comment: Didn't took it as bad criticism, so no wories @Nathan_Sav